# SVN Externals migration

Tags: svn

I have an SVN repo with dozens of externals. All the externals are defined with reference to "old_svr". The repo was moved to a new server, "new_svr" and all the externals references must be changed to refer to "new_svr" instead of "old_svr".

Do do so:
1) I checked out the repo from new server as is, which means all the externals still point to "old_svr"
2) I cd in the top directory for my working copy and ran

> svn propget -R svn:externals . > old_externals.tmp
>   3) I changed "old_svr" to "new_svr" in the file old_externals.tmp
>   sed 's/old_svr/new_svr/g' old_externals.tmp > new_externals.tmp
>   4) I applied the new externals definitions to my working copy
>   propset svn:externals -F new_externals.tmp
>   5) Commit the change
>   svn commit
>   6) Update the working copy
>   svn update

At this point I get lots of errors:
A) svn: warning: URL 'svn://new_svr/path/tag/directory' at revision 123 doesn't exist
B) There are still references to the old server
   svn: warning: Unknown hostname 'old_svr'

Questions: 
- how to effectively remove all the referencs to old_svr so that it does not come up anymore.
- I do not know why for some externals directories (most of them go through fine) svn cannot find a proper version to update.

YorgZ

Answer (score 1):

You have at least (at first sight) *two errors* and *one methodological flaw*:

- syntax of `svn ps` is wrong for externals (and thus you'll not be able propset all in one command)
- (possible small mistake) `svn pg > file` write file with empty line after each definition,`-F` for ps require "definition per line" and accept only # as comment-line
- **BIG FLAW** - you didn't read commands descriptions carefully and ignored error-output

### In short:

Your `svn ps` just do nothing (or you had another `ps`?!)

```
>svn ps svn:externals -F z:\externals.new
svn: E205001: Try 'svn help propset' for more information
svn: E205001: Explicit target argument required
```

### Longer:

You **must** to use one (correct) propset for every definition (in current form, when externals are scattered over the repo)

You **can** to use one (correct) propset for all definition, if you refactor their definitions previously (good time for it anyway) and collect all definitions in one repository-node (LOCALPATH have to be changed in the process): for local folder /Data/Collection (link to externals) it's definition can be

```
Data - file:///Z:/Repo1/trunk/Collection Collection
```

(in scattered model)

```
. - file:///Z:/Repo1/trunk/Collection Data/Collection
```

(in concentrated /in trunk-root/ model)

with the identical final result (the same externals on the same node of repo-tree)

Comment: Thanks for your answers Lazy Badger, it all makes sense and indeed I was trying to set the external all at once instead of going directory by directory.

Comment: I get the following errors now after >svn update.  I am not sure why some external pass and other fails. If the new host I am using was failing I would expect all externals to error out not just some. I do not understand the reference to a version number why is svn expecting a specific version. svn: warning: Error handling externals definition for 'Settings':
svn: warning: URL 'svn://new-svr/main-trunk/branches/PROJECT2/Settings' at revision 290 doesn't exist
At revision 569.

Comment: you'll need to delete the WC copy of the external and then do an svn update on the parent, that will gather the new relocated version.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your environment. Use up-to-date Subversion server and clients.

Beginning with Subversion 1.5, that was released years ago (in 2008), it was recommended to use repository-relative URLs in `svn:externals`. Using them helps in such cases because the URL to the repository can be changed and `svn:externals` modification not required. Check [SVNBook | Externals definitions](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/externals/) for more information on repo-relative URLs.

Comment: Sorry, but you MISS here. If externals point to **another host** (which changed in time), relative URLs can't help

Comment: @LazyBadger yep, you are right. In such case OP has to reconfigure all externals.

Comment: I was trying to reconfigure all the externals on my working copy and then commit and update but it did not work. SVN is trying to pull externals from a specific revision and cannot find them. I cannot find a way around getting the person that created the external in the first place to modify the original repo.

Comment: @YorgZ: "t did not work" isn't good answer or description of problem. **HOW** it doesn't work? Show full log!!! We aren't sensitives and, btw, "it work for me"